# mod_rewrite that operates on relative paths in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want Apache to convert or redirect

```
example.com/someController/someAction/5
```

to

```
example.com/?c=someController&a=someAction&id=123
```

I would like to put some mod_rewrite rules in a .htaccess file I can put in the same directory as index.php. In the example above .htaccess and index.php is in the example.com-folder.

I would like the rules to operate on relative paths so it would work if my site was on another domain and in a subdirectory. Example:

```
otherdomain.com/subdirectory/someController/someAction/5
```

to

```
otherdomain.com/subdirectory/?c=someController&a=someAction&id=123
```

In this example, index.php and .htaccess is inside the "subdirectory" folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1?c=$2&a=$3&id=$4
```

Comment: What would the complete contents of .htaccess be?

Comment: @arex1337: You would just need to add the obligatory `RewriteEngine on`.